# Pagination in a table with dynamic entries from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ajax

I am creating a page which is dynamically fetching entries from a JSON file and is displaying it in the form of table I have written the code to create the table in Java script, but it is fetching all the entries at once. I'm trying to create a pagination with only 10 entries per page and trying to create a sort. Here's the function for creating the table.

```js
  function myFunction32() 
    {
       var table = document.getElementById("contentTable");
       table.innerHTML = "";
       var row = table.insertRow(0);
       var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
       var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
       var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
       var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
       var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      
       cell1.innerHTML = "Disk ID";
       cell2.innerHTML = "Serial Number";
       cell3.innerHTML = "Hypervisor IP";
       cell4.innerHTML = "TIER";
       cell5.innerHTML = "Total Capacity";
  
   for(var i=0; disk.length;i++)
   {
   var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
   var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
   
   cell1.innerHTML = disk[i].disk_id;
   cell2.innerHTML = disk[i].disk_serial_id;
   cell3.innerHTML = disk[i].hypervisor_ip;
   cell4.innerHTML = disk[i].storage_tier;
   cell5.innerHTML = disk[i].disk_size +" GiB";
   
   }
```

I have updated the code to include 10 entries per page, but I am not able to create a new button for next page along with sorting.

I am calling my table in the HTML as follows

```html
<div id="fatal" style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:10px;">
      <table id = "contentTable" class="table table-bordered"></table>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I solved using jQuery [datatable](http://datatables.net), take a look on my gist https://gist.github.com/dptole/08f090b3cbe00e8ba937. You gonna have to edit and apply to your scenario.

From line 65 to 67 I have a wrapper to return the API endpoint string, without actually requesting it.